# Python file renaming syntax error

Tags: python, regex, rename, glob

I need to rename many files with the following format:

```
509938_OPS001_ACTCGCTA-TCGACTAG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

I've tested my regex:

```
\d+\w([OPS]+\d+)[_]\w+-\w+[_](\d+)(\.fastq\.gz)
```

I've tried many versions of the following script, but each throws a syntax error following re.sub.

```
import glob, re, os

for filename in glob.glob('some/dir/*.fastq.gz'):
    new_name = re.sub(\d+\w([OPS]+\d+)[_]\w+-\w+[_](\d+)(\.fastq\.gz), r'\1_\2\3', filename)
    os.rename(filename, new_name)

$python fastq_rename.py
  File "fastq_rename.py", line 6
    new_name = re.sub(\d+\w([OPS]+\d+)[_]\w+-\w+[_](\d+)(\.fastq\.gz)), r'\1_\2\3', filename)
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Presuming this has to do with an unescaped backslash, I've enclosed the regex with `r' '`, and this avoids the error, but does not change filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_name = re.sub(r'\d+\w([OPS]+\d+)[_]\w+-\w+[_](\d+)(\.fastq\.gz)', r'\1_\2\3', filename)
new_name="some/dir/"+newname
```

Enclose regex in `r`.Also the `newname` parameter to `os.rename` should include filepath or else it will rename file to the directory from where script if being called.

Comment: Thank you, the filepath was key!